# How to get current view from other view controller?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller

I am now doing sign in/sign out feature for my app.When i try to sign out,i want to called the current view controller ViewDidAppear().Because I want to refresh the view to lock that label that are only available for sign in user.So I need to know which current view controller that is displaying in my app.
Any help?

Answer (score 1):

If you are in navigation controller, you can get the VC on top.

```
self.navigationController?.topViewController
```

will return you the ViewController on top of the stack.

You can check [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationController/topViewController) for other options.

To point a few:

- > **var topViewController: UIViewController?**
  >   The view controller at the top of the navigation stack.
- > **var visibleViewController: UIViewController?**
  >   The view controller
  >   associated with the currently visible view in the navigation
  >   interface.
- > **var viewControllers: [UIViewController]**
  >                               The view controllers
  >   currently on the navigation stack.

Comment: I am not getting the current view when I try to output with "println(self.nvc?.topViewController)" which keep showing me nil.But i am trying to do from my left slide menu.Is that a problem.If so,how to get the main view that was cover by slide menu?